# How to build samples from spring-security source

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, gradle

I check out the source of spring security from github, and I want to run the "contacts" example in the samples directory(the samples directory has a subdirectory named contacts-xml), I tried the method according to http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/build.html, I run the cas demo successfully by command

> gradlew cas

and it works.

But when I tried

> gradle jettyRun

in the contacts-xml directory, I got a error message

```
nine@nine:~/codes/spring-security/samples/contacts-xml$ gradle jettyRun
:buildSrc:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:compileGroovy
:buildSrc:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:classes
:buildSrc:jar
:buildSrc:assemble
:buildSrc:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:compileTestGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:test UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:check UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:build
The ConfigurationContainer.add() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Please use the create() method instead.
The TaskContainer.add() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Please use the create() method instead.
The Test.testResultsDir property has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Please use the Test.getReports().getJunitXml().setDestination() property instead.
The Test.testReportDir property has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Please use the Test.getReports().getHtml().getDestination() property instead.
'appEngineSdkRoot' must be set in gradle.properties
2013-10-15 10:01:59.832:INFO::Logging to STDERR via org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog

FAILURE: Could not determine which tasks to execute.

* What went wrong:
**Task 'jettyRun' not found in project ':spring-security-samples-contacts-xml'.**

* Try:
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks.

**BUILD FAILED**
```

Am I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says that you need to navigate to the specific subdirectory:

`cd samples/contacts`

Comment: I have already in samples/contacts-xml directory when run the "gradle jettyRun" command.

Comment: Seems like they switched their examples to using the Tomcat plugin instead. The documentation is out-of-date. You will need to run the task `tomcatRun` instead: `../../gradlew tomcatRun`.